# MVC .Net Core - Export DB content as .csv file

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, export-to-csv

In my application I recieve JSON data but never know what fields it will contain. What I'd like to do is convert the list of JSON strings into a .csv file and return it as a file result. The tricky thing is I never know what or how many fields the JSON will contain. It could be one field per object or several, with names I cannot predict. All the solutions I found are for set object structures where you can parse the JSON to a c# class that matches the JSON's structure.

Is there a way to easily parse the JSON into a dynamic object and then serializing it into a CSV? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

## Edit

I found [this](https://github.com/jitbit/CsvExport) simple export tool that could work using the `PropertyInfo` of the `dynamic` object. Suggestions?

## Edit 2

Okay, so I'm not using `dynamic` objects anymore, it just makes stuff more complicated. I'm parsing my JSON into a `Dictionary<string, string>`, since I realized my JSON only consists of key value pairs. That works flawlessly. Now I need a way to serialize it into CSV, and I would like headers. The CSV export tool I mentioned before doesn't work the way I want, it doesn't support headers and for some reason it adds `sep=` in the first line. I haven't found a CSV serializer that works without an Object to go off of. Why is this so complicated?

Comment: I don't know why someone vote this question down. But Json can be treated as a tree-like object while the csv can be considered as a table-like file. There's no standard way to convert a tree-like object to a thing of table-like. I think it's better to tell us how you decide to map a property of `a.b.c.d` to a field in the table.

Comment: To make it clear, I'm asking how to convert the json string `{
"x":"ss",
"z":{"c1":"c1","c2":"c2"},
"a":[1,2,3]
}` to csv ?

Comment: @itminus luckily my JSON object doesn't have arrays or more objects in it. it's just key-value pairs. So far I've figured out how to parse the JSON into a dynamic type, but I'll have to figure out if that works with `PropertyInfo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're assuming the property are simple properties, we can simply treat a property of json as a field in csv.

To make the code clear and clean, I define a `Row` as `SortedDictionary<string,string>` :

```
using Row =SortedDictionary<string,string>;
```

I also write a helper class to export json to csv.

```
public class JsonToCsvExporter{

    public JsonToCsvExporter(string json,string sep=","){
        this._json = json;
        this.Sep = sep;
        this.Rows = new List<Row>();
        this.Headers = new List<string>();
        this.Initialize(json);
    }

    private string _json ;

    public IList<Row> Rows{get;set;}
    public IList<string> Headers { get; set; }
    public string Sep {get;set;}=",";

    private void Initialize(string json){
        var o = JArray.Parse(json);
        this.BuildRows(o, null);
        this.Headers = this.Rows.FirstOrDefault().Keys.ToList();
        this.NormailizeRows();
    }
    private void BuildRows(IEnumerable<JToken> tokens, Row row){
        if(row == null){ row = new Row(); }
        foreach( var token in tokens){
            if (token.Type == JTokenType.Property)
            {
                JProperty prop = (JProperty)token;
                if (!prop.Value.HasValues){
                    row.Add(prop.Name,prop.Value.ToString());
                }
            }
            // if it is not a `JProperty`, they shoud have children,
            //     that means it shoud be treated as a brand new line 
            else if (token.HasValues){
                var _row = new Row();
                BuildRows(token.Children(),_row);
            }
        }
        // if current row has fields, add this row
        if (row.Count>0) {
            this.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }

    // add null for unspecified values
    private void NormailizeRows() {
        foreach (var row in Rows) {
            foreach (var header in Headers) {
                if (!row.ContainsKey(header)) {
                    row.Add(header,null);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task ForEach<T>(IEnumerable<T> items,Func<T,Task> funcForFirst,Func<T,Task> funcForEach ){
        if(funcForFirst== null ){ throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(funcForFirst));}
        if(funcForEach== null ){ throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(funcForEach));}

        var iter = items.GetEnumerator();
        var flag= iter?.MoveNext();
        if(flag==false){ throw new Exception("items MUST have at least one element");}

        await funcForFirst(iter.Current);

        while(iter.MoveNext()!= false){
            await funcForEach(iter.Current);
        }
    }

    public async Task ExportHeader(StreamWriter writer){
        await this.ForEach(this.Headers,
            async header=>{
                await writer.WriteAsync(header);
            },
            async header=>{
                await writer.WriteAsync(this.Sep);
                await writer.WriteAsync(header);
            }
        );
        await writer.WriteLineAsync();
    }

    public async Task ExportBody(StreamWriter writer)
    {
        foreach (var row in this.Rows) {
            await this.ForEach(row,
                async f=>{
                    await writer.WriteAsync(f.Value);
                },
                async f=>{
                    await writer.WriteAsync(this.Sep);
                    await writer.WriteAsync(f.Value);
                }
            );
            await writer.WriteLineAsync();
        }
    }

}
```

**How to Use and Test Case**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var json =@"[{
        'F1': 'hello1',
        'F2': 'world1',
        'F3': 'foo1',
        'F4': 'bar2',
    },{
        'F1': 'Hello2',
        'F4': 'Bar2',
    },{
        'F1': 'Hello3',
        'F2': 'World3',
        'F3': null,
        'F4': 'Bar3',
    }]";
    var fs= new FileStream("xxxx.csv",FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    using(var writer = new StreamWriter(fs)){
        var exporter= new JsonToCsvExporter(json);
        exporter.ExportHeader(writer).Wait();
        exporter.ExportBody(writer).Wait();
        fs.Flush();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: wow - thanks for the extensive answer. I've already figured it out though, I guess I should have updated the question or posted my solution.. sorry for making you do unnecessary work. very nice solution though! ill accept it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I accepted itminus's answer due to him finding a suitable solution, and putting a bunch of work into it. Though, I figured it out beforehand. Here is my own solution:

To parse I'm using good 'ol Newtonsoft.Json and to serialize to CSV I'm using jitbit's CsvHelper, as mentioned in the question. My solution takes a `List<string>` filled with a bunch of JSON objects, which each have the same structure, but the structure is unknown. The only given is that the JSON is filled with key-value pairs, and doesn't contain arrays or more, "deeper" objects.

```
[Authorize]
public class ExportController : Controller
{
    //Dependency-Injection of database context
    private readonly VoteDbContext c;
    public ExportController(VoteDbContext Context)
    {
        c = Context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public FileResult Feedback()
    {
        //get all feedback records
        List<string> jsonData = c.UserFeedback.Select(x => x.Data).ToList();
        //example JSON in this list:
        // {"key1":"val1", "key2":"val2", ...}

        CsvExport csvExport = new CsvExport();

        foreach (string json in jsonData)
        {
            //parse json into usable object
            Dictionary<string, string> currentData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

            //add new row for each record
            csvExport.AddRow();
            //add values for row
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in currentData)
                csvExport[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
        }

        //return the generated csv file
        return File(csvExport.ExportToBytes(true)/*true -> with header*/, "text/csv", "Feedback.csv");
    } 
}
```

I want to return it as a file from the MVC Controller, so the return type is `FileResult` and I'm returning the output of the `File()` method.